# Does passing the Activity Context to an singleton affect the getContentResolver()?

Tags: android, download, android-contentresolver, scoped-storage

**Problem:**I'm updating an app to Android 11 (API 30) and I cannot get the `getContentResolver()` to work in the following instance though it works elsewhere.

With help from this forum and reading the Scoped Storage docs, elsewhere in the app, the following code works within the `Actiities` they reside; which includes inputting and outputting from the shared download folder using the `getContentResolver()`. The file types are a variety.

**What I'm trying to do:** This app also allows a user (with approved permissions) to attach a variety of files (e.g., docs, audio, video, etc.) to notes in a database. In this case, a PDF. However, the file information gets passed to a `Singleton` class created to avoid redundancy in the same code within other `activities`, so I just pass the `Context` if needed.

As I mentioned, this code works fine when contained within the `Activity` and the only difference I see is the context is passed to a singleton class. I was hoping someone would see something I'm not.

I do realize the URI is not passed (see the `resultLauncher` code, but I don't believe that really matters, I can take the file path and change it to an URI, which I have successfully multiple times. Aside from passing to a singleton class, this is the only difference (I can see) compared to my other code.

I could be way off here, the first app and all. A user needs to have the option to attach multiple file types.

```
**INTENT**
 btnAddFile.setOnClickListener(v -> {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     intent.setType("*/*");
     resultLauncher.launch(intent);

 });
```

**RESULT LAUNCHER**

```
 resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
     if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){
  Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
  String util = UriUtils.getPathFromUri(this, uri);
  tableLayoutFiles.addView(BuildTableLayout.setupFilesTableRow(EditNote.this,tableLayoutFiles, util,false));
     }
 });
```

**CODE WITHIN SINGLETON CLASS METHOD** (a `TableLayout` of files and file paths `TextViews` are passed. So the following code resides in a loop iterating the `TextView` (i.e., tv) file paths.

```
File f = new File(tv.getText().toString());
String n = f.getName();
try {
     InputStream fis = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(new File(f.getPath())));
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     for (int read; (read = fis.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
  bos.write(buf, 0, read);
     }
     fis.close();

     noteFiles.add(new Files(0, n, bos.toByteArray()));
 } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("getContentResolver", e.toString());
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved my own problem and as I suspected, I had to pass the `Uri` directly to the `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` and could not convert a path using `Uri.fromFile()`. Another learners experience.

Adding a new variable `HashMap<String, Uri>()` called `fileURIs` to my method, I passed the file `Uri` to my method. I used a file path as the key and the file's `Uri` as the key value. I updated the `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` within the `for` loop to retrieve the correct file `Uri`.

**Update:**

```
InputStream fis = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileURIs.get(f.getPath()));
```

---

```
 File f = new File(tv.getText().toString());
 String n = f.getName();
 try {
     InputStream fis = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileURIs.get(f.getPath()));
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     for (int read; (read = fis.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
         bos.write(buf, 0, read);
     }
     fis.close();

     noteFiles.add(new Files(0, n, bos.toByteArray()));
 } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("getContentResolver", e.toString());
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

And I should clarify, the use of `Uri.fromFile()` does work on file/directories that are not "access denied", so passing a `cache` file path can be passed to the `ContextResolver()` without issue in this fashion. In my case, when files are imported from an xml, they get moved to the cache directory which eliminates the issue and why `Uri.fromFile()` works. That was part of my confusion and not being fully eductated on scoped storage.